# Can't find the page to generate the OAuth token

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign with java and used to test it with OAuth generator on the DocuSign website. But now I can't find the OAuth generator. Where is it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token generator has been removed. The idea now is that developers use our quick start examples since they include oauth examples to generate an access token: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/